# emitting index-hml-webpack-plugin EISDIR: ilegal operation on a directory, read

Tags: angularjs, npm

[image: im developing single application using AngularJS and MVC when I publish asp.net MVC, AngularJS is not deployed on the published folder so I tried to deploy manually the AngularJS using "ng build" but suddenly an error appears after 95% progress "emitting index-hml-webpack-plugin EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read, I don't know where is this coming from. "]

it stops on the emitting `index-html-webpack-plugin`

I tried so many updates on my code and configuration but nothing's work on it,
please help me to solve this error thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have correct file path specified for 'index' in angular.json.

EISDIR means that the target of the operation is a directory in reality but that the expected filetype of the target is something other than a directory.

Note: if you upgraded your angular project there is a possibility that index path has automatically changed to director instead of correct template i.e. index.html